# Properties with Long type and properties with Integer type

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, long-integer

```
 <div class="mb-3 col-md-6">
     <label asp-for="@Model.MERSISNumber" class="form-label">MERSIS Numarası</label>
     <input class="form-control" type="text" id="taxNumber" asp-for="@Model.MERSISNumber" name="mersis" placeholder="MERSIS Numarası" />                                 
 </div>


 <div class="mb-3 col-md-6">
     <label asp-for="@Model.TaxNumber" class="form-label">Vergi Numarası</label>
     <input class="form-control" type="text" id="taxNumber" asp-for="@Model.TaxNumber" name="taxNumber" placeholder="Vergi Numarası" />                                 
 </div>




[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(CompanyCreateVM companyCreateVM, IFormFile imgFile)
{
    try
    {
        if (imgFile != null)
        {

            await UploadImage(companyCreateVM, imgFile);
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(companyCreateVM), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("/CreateCompany", content);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("List", "Admin");
            }

        }
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Geçersiz istek veya dosya seçilmedi.");
        return View(companyCreateVM);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Bir hata oluştu: {ex.Message}");
        return View(companyCreateVM);
    }
}
```

I want to input the MERSIS number in the first div. The second div is created for entering the tax number. The type of the tax number is integer, and the type of the MERSIS number is long. After entering the values, when I click the save button, the value of the tax number parameter is sent to Create, but each time the value of the MERSIS number appears as 0. What could be the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should not set the `id` and `name` attributes manually when using `asp-for` tag helper. `asp-for` automatically generates these attributes and sets the appropriate values to them so that model binding can work.

The reason MERSIS number is always 0 is that the property name is `MERSISNumber` but your input has `name="mersis"`. If you remove `name="mersis"` attribute then the tag helper will generate it with the correct value. You can inspect the generated `name` attribute using your browsers developer tools.